# Amazon EC2 Root login

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I'm trying to enable root login for my EC2 instances. I know I could use `su` or `sudo`, but I need to be able to ssh'ing into my server as root because the Jenkins EC2-Plugin requires root access.

I already found some solutions during my web search but they all didn't work:

- `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Copy `authorized_keys` to root's `.ssh`-Folder

This link seemed to be quite useful but also didn't work: http://teknika.tumblr.com/post/5416465911/jenkins-ec2

Comment: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is the file to edit to put in `PermitRootLogin`.

Comment: As I already mentioned this doesn't work (yes I restarted the ssh daemon)

Comment: just pointing out the difference in file names, as you mentioned `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, but the daemon uses `sshd_config`. If that was just a typo, sorry. But otherwise, once you edited `sshd_config` and restarted, what does it say when you do `ssh root@yourinstanceip`?

Comment: Damn, shame... Thanks! I never saw the typo... Changed `PermitRootLogin` to yes in `sshd_config` solved the problem!

Comment: @Tom, putting "Solved: in the title does not mark the question as solved in the UI. If you solved it yourself you should add an answer saying what you did and, after a day or so, click the checkmark in your answer. That will mark it as solved, and if someone searches for the same question SO will show them your answer, possibly getting you a few rep points.

Comment: The steps [described here](http://gurjeet-tech.blogspot.com/2012/02/allowing-root-access-in-amis.html) worked for me.

Answer (score 62):

Refer to the following to set root login:

```
sudo -s (to become root)
vi /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Delete the lines at the begining of the file until you get to the words `ssh-rsa`.

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Set the variable `PermitRootLogin` to `PermitRootLogin without-password` (without quotes)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: I was able to do this without the `without-password` part (RHEL platform)

Comment: Google brought me here looking for a way to login as root without password. That `sudo -s` was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

- Comment out the line "PermitRootLogin"
- Comment out the line "PasswordAuthentication no"

Then restart the ssh service

```
/sbin/service sshd restart
```

Comment: I did a variation of this on Amazon and it worked. Instead of commenting out `PasswordAuthentication no`, I made it `PasswordAuthentication yes`. However, I did comment out `PermitRootLogin` and restarted SSH.

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit file : /etc/ssh/sshd_config
and restart ssh service .

1. If you want to login using keys change as below :

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   RSAAuthentication yes
   ```
2. If you want to login using password , change as below :

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Try this when you authenticate with your key:

```
$user@instance: sudo su
```

or assign a password with:

```
$user@instance: sudo su passwd
```

and change the password to enter with `sudo su`.

Answer (score 4):

1. ssh into EC2 as a normal user
2. ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. ```
   cd ~
   ```
4. Edit the authorized_keys

   ```
   vim .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
5. remove the part which is not the key make sure the file will start with

   ssh-rsa ............................
6. Save the file and try to login as a root

   ```
   ssh root@servername
   ```

Answer (score 2):

sudo -i for root access once you are login with ec2-user with the pem file in ssh client

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -su` for changing to root login and switching from any user whether it is ec2-user or centos or any user.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:
`vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Set:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Then:
`service sshd restart`

Now I can login using winscp as root

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

sudo passwd root (assign password)

su (password)

nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

systemctl restart sshd

nano /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

```
Delete only
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo
'Please login as the user \"admin\" rather than the user
\"root\".';echo;sleep 10;exit 142"
```

Leave authorized_keys

```
ssh-ed25519
ssh-rsa
```